# How to download .rar file(Attachment) containing .exe file in gmail

Tags: gmail

I am trying to download a .rar attachment in Gmail with .exe files, But Gmail virus scanners blocked the attachment from downloading. How can I download it ?

Comment: I think this belongs on superuser

Comment: Maybe it's a virus...

Comment: Its not a virus , it contains a java project which I did some years ago. I saved it in Gmail for future reference.

Comment: look here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590  Took 2 minutes with google to find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gmail's Android app lets you download blocked files or save them to Google Drive. 
I just saved it to my drive and yes, its working.

Answer (score 2):

Have the sender remove the exe file extension or change it to a "dummy" one, then when you download the file, change the extension back to exe.  For example, if you have a file called "virus.exe", rename it to "virus.virus" (or "virus" with no extension).  Then after downloading rename the file back to "virus.exe".

Answer (score 1):

Open email click the down arrow at right and select show original and save file as eml.
Here is the source which shows complete setup by step process and with video also

[Download blocked gmail files easy way](https://solutionspirit.com/download-gmail-blocked-attachments/)

Comment: Thanks alot 
The source is very helpful

Comment: @SHUJATMUNAWAR i am glad it helped